# Определить тип СПП

Tags: синтаксис, спп

*В научной литературе, где рассматриваются типы билингвизма, особый интерес вызывает стихийный билингвизм, который используется в различных сферах повседневного общения: на рынке, в магазине, общественном транспорте, в разных сферах обслуживания.*

Это СПП с однородным подчинением или с последовательным подчинением?

Answer (score 1):

**В** научной **литературе**, (1)где рассматриваются типы билингвизма,(2) особый интерес вызывает стихийный **билингвизм**, (3)который используется в различных сферах повседневного общения: на рынке, в магазине, общественном транспорте, в разных сферах обслуживания.

• Сначала в этом СПП находим главное предложение:
*В научной литературе особый интерес вызывает стихийный билингвизм.*

•• Затем определяем, к каким словам относятся придаточные:
придаточное (1)–(2) находится внутри главного предложения и зависит от существительного с предлогом "в литературе";
придаточное (3) находится после главного предложения и зависит от существительного "билингвизм".

Правила:

> **Последовательное** подчинение в СПП — это когда одно придаточное зависит от главного, второе — от первого придаточного, третье — от второго и так далее.
> **(!)** При **параллельном** подчинении все придаточные зависят от главного предложения, но от разных слов в нем.
> При **однородном** подчинении все придаточные зависят от главного предложения и отвечают на одинаковый вопрос.

••• Делаем вывод: это предложение с параллельным подчинением.

[Сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП)](https://skysmart.ru/articles/russian/slozhnopodchinyonnoe-predlozhenie-spp)